# Problems starting created virtualenv instance

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to use virtualenv on my development machine. I successfully created my new environment issuing `virtualenv venv` in /home/user/. When I try to activate it (from user location) with `sudo venv/bin/activate` I get `venv/bin/activate: command not found`.

Comment: make sure that `venv/bin/activate` exists: `ls -l venv/bin/activate`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't run `activate` as a script; you need to `source` it in your shell, since it affects the shell itself.

It probably also doesn't make any sense to run it under `sudo`.

Comment: Exactly. You would source it for the current env anyways. Good answer.

Comment: Just add extra info here. There is comments in the activate file, "This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*,  you cannot run it directly"

Comment: This was what I was looking for! Activating the isolated environment is crucial before any `pip` package installation.

Answer (score 7):

Check that the virtualenv is actually where you think:

```
stat /home/user/venv/bin/activate
```

If it is, then you need to source the file in:

```
source /home/user/venv/bin/activate
```

If the file doesn't exist, you've created the venv in a different location.